# How to zip files in certain time

Tags: c#, file, time, zip

I have a program for zipping files , but I don't know how to make it to zip automatically in certain time (for example every Friday at 5 pm). It has to be like the link in description  [LINK](http://www.febooti.com/products/automation-workshop/tutorials/zip-files-automatically-different-daily-archives.html)

Comment: You can use windows task scheduler. This isn't really answer. You need to search a bit more :) Also please provide more information on what environment and specs you are using.

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule it as a Task

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993(v=ws.11).aspx